# Android CameraX use case binding failed

Tags: android, android-camerax

Device: Huawei P40 Lite E
dependencies:

```
//CameraX dependencies
def camerax_version = "1.1.0-alpha03"

//ML kit for computer vision, needed for face detection
//bundled with app
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:face-detection:16.0.6'

//CameraX core library using camera implementation
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"
```

Stacktrace:

```
E/CameraManager: Use case binding failed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination is found for camera device - Id : 0.  May be attempting to bind too many use cases. Existing surfaces: [] New configs: [androidx.camera.core.impl.PreviewConfig@eec1a35, androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageAnalysisConfig@4817eca, androidx.camera.core.impl.ImageCaptureConfig@a00b83b]
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.LifecycleCameraRepository.bindToLifecycleCamera(LifecycleCameraRepository.java:278)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:428)
        at androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(ProcessCameraProvider.java:302)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

code:

```
// Unbind use cases before rebinding
cameraProvider.unbindAll();

//preview
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
  .setTargetResolution(new Size(previewWidth, previewHeight))
  .setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0) //ROTATION_90 // //rotation
  .build();

preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

//viewport defines the buffer rect visible to end users
final ViewPort viewPort = new ViewPort.Builder(new Rational(previewWidth, previewHeight), ROTATION_0).build(); //rotation

//picture callback
imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
  .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
  .setBufferFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
  .setTargetResolution(new Size(pictureWidth, pictureHeight))
  .setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0) //rotation
  .build();


//face detection analysis
imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
  //ensure that backpressure strategy is set to its default strategy for real-time analysis
    .setBackpressureStrategy(STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .setTargetResolution(new Size(previewWidth, previewHeight))
    .setTargetRotation(ROTATION_0) //rotation
  .build();


setFaceDetector(imageAnalysis, 0.05f); //0.1f

//use UseCaseGroup to assign viewport to use cases
UseCaseGroup useCaseGroup = new UseCaseGroup.Builder()
  .addUseCase(preview)
  .addUseCase(imageAnalysis)
  .addUseCase(imageCapture)
  .setViewPort(viewPort)
  .build();

this.camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) activity, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup); //preview, imageAnalysis, imageCapture
^^^^^^ fails here on this line ^^^^^^^
```

Specifically only fails on the Huawei phone, while e.g. OnePlus 5T, Pixel 3, Galaxy phones, I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simultaneous ImageCapture in YUV and ImageAnalysis in YUV isn't supported on all camera devices; if you switch the ImageCapture to JPEG you should be fine on all devices (if you want details, you can look at the [tables](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) in the underlying camera2 API's session creation).  LIMITED-level camera devices only support 3 outputs if one of them is JPEG. FULL-level devices should support it, though.

That's why setBufferFormat is not part of the CameraX public API - using it easily pushes you out of the set of outputs that are commonly supported by camera devices.

Comment: That actually made sense. I was already looking into `CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL` and found that some devices (mainly Huawei) have limited camera2 API access, denoted using `CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED`. Other devices where I didn't have this error have FULL or LEVEL_3 support so that explains it. Thanks, this actually solved it for me.